# Polynomials satisfying $f(\operatorname{Tr} A) =\operatorname{Tr}(f(A)) $

Tags: matrices

Find all the polynomials $f\in \mathbb{C} [X]$ so that $f(\operatorname{Tr} A) =\operatorname{Tr}(f(A)) $, $\forall A \in M_n\mathbb(C)$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I have thought to use that the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, but I haven't got any further.

Comment: Hint: you should focus on all known properties of trace. Can't you see one in particular that could be very useful?

Comment: Your starting point is good. What are the eigenvalues of $f(A)$?

Comment: Use diagonal matrices to reduce the statement to real numbers. For example, what is the trace of a diagonal matrix? If $A$ is diagonal, can you evaluate $f(A)$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** To use OP's observation in the comments, we'll need to know the generalized eigenvalues of $f(A)$: If the generalized eigenvalues of $A$ are (including multiplicity) $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$, then those of $f(A)$ are $f(\lambda_1), \ldots, f(\lambda_n)$. Thus, the condition $f(\operatorname{tr} A) = \operatorname{tr} f(A)$ becomes
$$f(\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n) = f(\lambda_1) + \cdots + f(\lambda_n) .$$

On the other hand, for any $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \in \Bbb C$, there is a matrix in $M_n(\Bbb C)$ whose eigenvalues are $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ (for example, $\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$).